# Compare two CSV files and write difference in the same file as an extra column in python

Tags: python, csv

Hey intelligent community,

I need a little bit of help because i think i don't see the the wood in the trees.

i have to CSV files that look like this:

```
Name,Number
AAC;2.2.3
AAF;2.4.4
ZCX;3.5.2


Name,Number
AAC;2.2.3
AAF;2.4.4
ZCX;3.5.5
```

I would like to compare both files and than write any changes like this:

```
Name,Number,Changes
AAC;2.2.3
AAF;2.4.4
ZCX;5.5.5;change: 3.5.2
```

So on every line when there is a difference in the number, i want to add this as a new column at the end of the line.
The Files are formated the same but sometimes have a new row so thats why i think i have to map the keys.

I come this far but now iam lost in my thoughts:

Python 3.10.9

> ```
> import csv
>
> Reading the first csv and set mapping
> with open('test1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
> reader= csv.reader(csvfile)
> rows = list(reader)
> file1_dict = {row[1]: row[0] for row in rows}
>
>
> Reading the second csv and set mapping
> with open('test2.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
> reader= csv.reader(csvfile)
> rows = list(reader)
> file2_dict = {row[1]: row[0] for row in rows}
>
> comparing the keys and find the diff
>
> for k in test1_dict:
> if test1_dict[k] != test2:dict[k]
> test1_dict[k] = test2_dict[k]
> for row in rows:
> if row[1] == k:
> row.append(test2_dict[k])
>
> #write the csv (not sure how to add the word "change:")
> with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline ='') as csvfile:
> writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
> writer.writerows(rows)
> ```

If i try this, i don't get a new column, it just "updates" the csv file with the same columns.

For example this code gives me the diff row but i'am not able to just add it to existing file and row.

```
with open('test1.csv') as fin1:
  with open('test2.csv') as fin2:
    read1 = csv.reader(fin1)
    read2 = csv.reader(fin2)
    diff_rows = (row1 for row1, row2 in zip(read1, read2) if row1 != row2)
    with open('test3.csv', 'w') as fout:
      writer = csv.writer(fout)
      writer.writerows(diff_rows)
```

Does someone have any tips or help for my problem? I read many answers on here but can't figure it out.

Thanks alot.

@bigkeefer
Thanks for your answer, i tried to change it for the delimiter ; but it gives an "list index out of range error".

```
with open('test3.csv', 'r') as file1:
    reader = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=';')
    rows = list(reader)[1:]
    file1_dict = {row[0]: row[1] for row in rows}
with open('test4.csv', 'r') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2, delimiter=';')
    rows = list(reader)[1:]
    file2_dict = {row[0]: row[1] for row in rows}
new_file = ["Name;Number;Changes\n"]
with open('output.csv', 'w') as nf:
    for key, value in file1_dict.items():
        if value != file2_dict[key]:
            new_file.append(f"{key};{file2_dict[key]};change: {value}\n")
        else:
            new_file.append(f"{key};{value}\n")
    nf.writelines(new_file)
```

Comment: are you able to use `pandas` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Iam not that good wth pandas. I tried two solutions but wasn't able to solve the problem :/

Comment: I mean: are you able to apply pandas solution if such would existed?

Comment: i want to start the script in jenkins or in a folder so i think i can apply a pandas solution if such would exist. @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adapt this to overwrite your first file etcetera, as you mentioned above, but I've left it like this for your testing purposes. Hopefully this will help you in some way.

I've assumed you've actually got the headers above in each file. If not, remove the slicing on the list creations, and change the `new_file` variable assignment to an empty list ([]).

```
with open('f1.csv', 'r') as file1:
    reader = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=";")
    rows = list(reader)[1:]
    file1_dict = {row[0]: row[1] for row in rows if row}
with open('f2.csv', 'r') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2, delimiter=";")
    rows = list(reader)[1:]
    file2_dict = {row[0]: row[1] for row in rows if row}
new_file = ["Name,Number,Changes\n"]
for key, value in file1_dict.items():
    if value != file2_dict[key]:
        new_file.append(f"{key};{file2_dict[key]};change: {value}\n")
    else:
        new_file.append(f"{key};{value}\n")
with open('new.csv', 'w') as nf:
    nf.writelines(new_file)
```

Comment: wow that works pretty much for what i looked. It works perfect with comma seperated files but when i try to change it for ; as a delimiter it get a "list index out of range" IndexError. Do you know why? 
I will comment my new code in the Answer section because its too long for this section.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask you about that (I thought maybe the semi-colons were a mistake/typo). It's because csv uses commas by default. I have edited the solution for your needs.

Comment: And, sorry again! I did not take in all of your comment and have just seen you have already done this in your edited question! (Need more coffee!) This works for me however. Have your file formats changed?

Comment: I suspect it's if any of your input files have blank lines, as I have recreated it now here. I have added a check for this on the dictionary comprehensions, which should fix it for you.